# Deep link not working with http localhost

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm trying to build a react native app, and I need to use deep-linking, in order to open my app from a link.

The thing is the deep-linking works from app Scheme, but not with http and https scheme. I also want to mention that I use localhost as the host, so maybe that's where it's wrong.

Here is my AndroidManifest file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.area">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
      android:name="com.area.MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="area" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

          <data android:scheme="http" android:host="localhost:8081" />
          <data android:scheme="https" android:host="localhost:8081" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you an see,

I've set `<data android:scheme="http" android:host="localhost:8081" />` and
`<data android:scheme="area" />`

Here is my React Navigation Linking configuration :

```
  const linking = {
    prefixes: ["area://", 'http://localhost:8081'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Login: 'Login',
        Register: 'Register',
        Auth: 'Auth',
        ForgotPassword: 'ForgotPassword',
        ResetPassword: 'ResetPassword',
        Homepage: '',
        Create: 'Create',
        Activity: 'Activity',
        User: 'Areas'
      }
    }
  };

  export default linking;
```

Now Everything should be working, so I tried to test my deep-links with theses commands:

`npx uri-scheme open area:// --android` which works and opens the app

[image]

and

`npx uri-scheme open http://localhost:8081 --android` which only opens the navigator

[image]

the localhost:8081 Web server is not on, but it's ok I just need the deep-link to kick-in and open the app.

What have I been doing wrong ?

Comment: seems like you do not understand what is localhost ... even on emulator it is emulated device itself - not its host  ... and you prolly don't have webserver setuped on emulator

Comment: I want the app to open the deep-link whenever the localhost url is opened, I know the localhost server is not running, the thing is I have a NestJS server which the React Native app will call to login via Oauth, then if Auth is valid, the server redirects the current navigator to the Web client page, since the web client is not hosted, I have to use localhost, and I would like to have the app using deep-links on localhost url to open the app rather than trying to load localhost which is not running on the device

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADB https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#testing-filters utility to check your deeplink:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "your deep link URL"
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I didn't work, It ended up using another solution

Comment: @Diamonddedo Did you get it to work with localhost? What is the other solution?